# Price calculator using angularJS

Tags: angularjs

I am working on an app which is price calculator. So, when user selects the country and the quantity(Forget about SMS Type) and clicks on pay online button, user should be getting the total according to the country currency.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Actually i am trying to build an app for a website. Which is price calculator. I have two inputs and a button. First input is drop down which is basically country name with currency and second field is where users can enter the quantity and once country and quantity is selected and user clicks on pay online then user should get the total amount on the screen.

Comment: You did not ask your question yet

Comment: if you need to convert the amount in specific currency based on country selected then the logic for conversion need to be added in controller's function which will take the country name and amount using ng-click and then calculate the price based on country selected.

Comment: That's still not a question.

Comment: may this help - https://developer.tizen.org/community/tip-tech/creating-complete-currency-calculator-application-angularjs-tizen-%E2%80%93-part-1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this basic example of what it may look like:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.value = 0;
  $scope.curr = [{
    "exchange": 1.0,
    "c": "UK",
    "s": "£"
  }, {
    "exchange": 1.38546,
    "c": "USA",
    "s": "$"
  }, {
    "exchange": 1.12987,
    "c": "EURO",
    "s": "€"
  }];
  $scope.selectedCurrency = $scope.curr[0];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>


<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

  <select ng-model="selectedCurrency" ng-options="x.c for x in curr">
</select><br>
  <input type="number" ng-model="value"><br> {{selectedCurrency.s}}{{selectedCurrency.exchange * value}}
</div>
```